# How to create a text file & write data to it using C#?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, text-files, file-handling

I have a text file which is continuously getting updated from the server data and as per my requirement, I have to create a new text file every midnight. As soon as the date changes, I need to write data from the server into the newly created text file.
The server side text file contains date-wise data like this:

```
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23
```

I want to run this program as a windows service which will execute every midnight and will do the above work.

I want to ask if this is possible with windows service.Can i use a timer to do this task?

Comment: What is the actual problem/question? Your sample shows data from multiple days, that contradicts "create a text file at every midnight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `scheduled task` is probably more appropriate, see e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx for a discussion.

To set up a scheduled task, just create a console application that does your job.

Comment: can i use schedule task in my windows form application?.Can this would run automatically without user intervention?

Comment: The task scheduler is a built in service in windows, where you can set up when a program or a script should be run. For instance you can set the scheduler to run a program called createtextfile.exe every day at midnight. Once the scheduler is set up, there is no user intervention needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible to use a service for this. But you might consider using the windows task scheduler for this instead and let the scheduler run a script or a small command line application that does what you want at every midnight.

Comment: +1 Agreed (and note that the Windows Task Scheduler is in fact a service itself!)